# Error "undefined is not a funcion" when performing a $.find

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

guys,
once again I come begging for help. I can't get my head around this - all I need is update the name attribute's indexes of texts in my form. I want to show to the user one line in the table and, as he/she clicks on the plus sign, another line is added.
For my form to work on the server side, I need do reindex the name parameter. That's how I'm trying to do it:

```
function reindex () {
$("table").find("tr.faixa").each(function(index, value) {
value.find("input.faixa_min").attr("name", "data[" + index + "][BonusRecarga][faixa_min]"); // <- here's where I get the error
value.find("input.faixa_max").attr("name", "data[" + index + "][BonusRecarga][faixa_max]");
value.find("input.valor_bonus").attr("name", "data[" + index + "][BonusRecarga][valor_bonus]");
value.find("input.perc_bonus").attr("name", "data[" + index + "][BonusRecarga][perc_bonus]");
});      
}
```

And here's a fragment of the form:

```
<tr class="faixa">
<td>
<input name="data[0][BonusRecarga][faixa_min]" class="faixa_min" type="text" required="required"/>
 </td>                  
<td>
<input name="data[0][BonusRecarga][faixa_max]" class="faixa_max" type="text" required="required"/>
</td>
<td>
<input name="data[0][BonusRecarga][valor_bonus]" class="valor_bonus" type="text" required="required"/>
</td>
<td>
<input name="data[0][BonusRecarga][perc_bonus]" class="perc_bonus input-small" type="text" required="required"/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="help-inline"><i class="icon-plus" style="cursor: pointer"></i></span>
<span class="help-inline"><i class="icon-minus" style="cursor: pointer"></i></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have also tried using a common for(var i = 0; i < $(".faixa").lenght; i++), but I always get the "undefined is not a function" in the first value.find(...). It looks like "value" doesn't have the find() method, but when I log it, it shows me a regular "....

Do you know why the find() method is not working on the "value" variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`value` is a DOM Element object while `.find()` is a jQuery method. You need to create a jquery object :

```
var $value = $(value);
//Then use $value.find()
```

Comment: Fast and precise. It was the root of the problem, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$(this).find('input...')...` . it works, and is better inside `each`.

Answer (score -1):

A much faster result for jquery would be to use the EQ function and append.
https://api.jquery.com/eq/

if EQ is not what your looking for leave a comment and ill look further into your issue.